# Is there correlation between friction of boundary layer and values of inlet and outlet pressure?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, turbines, cfd

Is there correlation between friction of boundary layer(or inertia and viscous forces in boundary layer) and values of inlet and outlet pressure in an axial turbine? For example, when friction of boundary layer decrease or boundary layer is not captured well, how to change values of inlet and outlet pressure in a turbine?

Comment: What would cause the friction of the boundary layer to decrease? What do you mean by captured well? Are you trying to compensate for a simulation that isn't working?